# javascript numbers, strings, math, and the proper way

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a javascript / jquery code that takes in a formula and numbers from the user and solves the equation. My code in jquery can get the solution down to real numbers, but in the form of a string and I can't get javascript to solve the equation mathematically.

I have something like

```
1000 * (200+3928)/2333
```

However, those numbers are all in string format and forcing each of them into floats or integers and reinserting them only turns them back into a string. Tried using valueOf and other things, but nothing works. Is there a better way or something I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: You will probably have to use regular expressions to break appart the equation into parts, while remembering the operators of the given equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a simple equation in the form of a string, the most practical method is to parse the string into `prefix` or `postfix` notation, then evaluate it accordingly...

Assuming the original string is `infix` (the notation humans use to learn basic math) such as...

`1000 * (200+3928)/2333`

You then convert it to `postfix` to obtain...

`1000, 200, 3928, +, *, 2333, /`

Using this notation, a computer can easily evaluate the expression using a simple loop and stack...

I wont post actual code, because I want to leave the fun parts up to you, but if you'd like a headstart with psuedo code, here goes...

```
infix to postfix :

  create empty array `postfix` and `temp`

  split the expression up into an array `A` by each operand/operator

  foreach token in `A`:
    if char is operand :
      push to postfix stack
    if char is open parenthesis:
      push to temp stack
    if char is close parenthesis:
      while top of temp stack != '(' :
        push top of temp stack to postfix stack
        pop top of temp stack
      end while
      pop top of temp stack
    if char is operator:
      while temp stack isn't empty *and* top of temp stack != '(' *and* precendence(char) <= precendence(top of temp stack) :
        push top of temp stack to postfix stack
        pop top of temp stack
      end while
      push char to temp stack

  end for loop

  while temp stack is not empty
    push top of temp stack to postfix stack
    pop top of temp stack
  end while

  return postfix stack (will be your postfix stack to evaluate)



evaluate postfix stack:
  create array A
  foreach token in postfix stack:
    if char is operand:
      push to A stack
    if char is operator:
      int x = pop A stack
      int y = pop A stack
      result = x (operation) y
      push result to A stack
  end for loop

  return top of A stack (this will be the final result)
```

Comment: When you say "pop the top" are you referring to solving the inner equation?

Comment: Hey, found a more detailed explanation so I get what you mean now. Thanks for the help. There are a lot of us pseudo-coders that appreciate these pushes in the right direction from the CS type guys.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` are rather helpful. Be sure to include your radix though so as to properly parse values.

```
var first = "1000", // String
    secnd = "25.2", // String
    third = parseInt(first, 10) * parseFloat(secnd); // Number
```

If you're in to brevity, at the cost of losing some readability, you can also cast strings to numbers using the `+` operator:

```
+"23"; // 23
+"2.3"; // 2.3
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bj74v/1/

Comment: There is no radix for [parseFloat](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3), the second argument will be ignored. If it is unknown whether the number is an integer or float, better to just use parseFloat (or some other method for converting strings to numbers, like the Number function, or unary `+`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make a free form calculator, you've got two choices.  You could use `eval()` to directly calculate the result, like elclanrs said.  But then the user can type in arbitrary Javascript code, so this is not recommended.  Your second option is to create a expression parser and evaluator.  If you want to deal with parentheses and stuff, it's not difficult, but it's also not exactly trivial.  Here's one example I found by searching for "javascript arithmetic parser":  http://code.google.com/p/js-equation-parser/.  It's open source, so check out the code if you want an idea of how it's done.

Answer (score -1):

You mean the user actually types `1000 * (200+3928)/2333` or are the numbers taken from different inputs and stored in variables to then calculate the result?

If it's the first case then you could use `eval`:

```
eval('1000 * (200+3928)/2333')
```

If it's the second case you can just prepend a `+` to your string thus converting it to a number like:

```
var num = +'1000'
```

Comment: User input should never be eval'ed. It should be parsed.